# Apache Airflow How to xcom_pull() value into a DAG?

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a custom operator which pushes XCOM value as below:

```
...
task_instance = context['task_instance']
task_instance.xcom_push("list_of_files",file_list)
...
```

It works fine. I have a dag definition file (my_dag.py) where I create a task by using my own operator, it pushes the XCOM value then I want to do for in loop by using this xcom value. How to pull it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't access the XCOM variable in your dag, it is only available in operators by supplying the `provide_context=True` argument to the operators constructor.

In the case where you want to use data from an operator in your DAG structure itself, you would need to perform the actual task your operator is performing outisde of an operator.

```
def get_file_list():
    hook = SomeHook()
    hook.run('something to get file list')

dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args)

for file in get_file_list():
    task = SomeOperator(params={'file': file}) # Do something with the file passed as a parameter
```

Answer (score 1):

It is generally bad practice to access xcom from the dag itself rather than from a task in the dag. That said, sometimes it is necessary. For example, you may need to do this when dynamically creating dags.

Here is an example of me pulling some unrun jobs within a dag. I'm using this in the context of a subdag, so I can rest assured that the xcom will always contain the information assuming the method is running.

```
    xcom_unrun_jobs = None
    if len(parent_dag.get_active_runs()) > 0:
        tis = parent_dag.get_task_instances(settings.Session, start_date=parent_dag.get_active_runs()[-1])[-1]
        xcom_unrun_jobs = tis.xcom_pull(dag_id=parent_dag._dag_id, task_ids=unrun_job_task_id)
```

Comment: Why is it bad practice? I have an inkling, but explaining it clearly would help me!